# What is the point of 'fmapDefault' in 'Data.Traversable'?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, traversable

I'm looking at the documentation for `Data.Traversable` and came across `fmapDefault` - https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base/Data-Traversable.html#g:3

```
fmapDefault :: Traversable t => (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
```

The documentation states that -

> This function may be used as a value for fmap in a Functor instance, provided that traverse is defined.

So presumably it can be used to derive an `fmap` for a `Traversable` instance. However, `Traversable` has `Functor` as a superclass.

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
    ...
```

So you cannot define a `Traversable` instance without defining the `Functor` instance first! And wherever you have a `Traversable`, you have access to an `fmap`, which is equivalent to (and perhaps more efficient than) `fmapDefault`.

So where would one use `fmapDefault`, instead of the much more familiar `fmap`?

Comment: "You cannot define a `Traversable` instance without defining the `Functor` instance first!" Well, "first" is such a squirrely term...

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit of a brain fart. Like assuming 1 comes before 2, due to years of counting procedurally from 0-10.  And then you consider the question - what comes first, '-1' or '-2', and are enlightened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It allows you to write

```
data Foo a = ...

instance Functor Foo where -- we do define the functor instance, but we “cheat”
  fmap = fmapDefault       -- by using `Traversable` in its implementation!

instance Traversable Foo where
  traverse = ...           -- only do this manually.
```

That said, I don't think this is really sensible. Functor instances are usually trivial to do by hand, and the obvious implementation will indeed likely be more efficient than a `Traversable` derived one. Usually, the instance can in fact be created automatically:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Foo a = ...
       deriving (Functor)
```

Comment: *Usually, the instance can in fact be created automatically [...]* Isn't that always the case?

Comment: @Jubobs: not quite, for some GADTs I have gotten errors about well-kindedness with `DeriveFunctor`. But possibly this was just a bug in GHC-7.8.

Comment: Damn, I had subconciously assumed that 'subclass' definitions cannot refer to 'superclass' definitions. Obviously that is a somewhat of an arbitrary requirement in hindsight. That's what you get when you have to use <OOP language of the day> half of the time.

Comment: @Jubobs `DeriveFunctor` also bails out if it sees a type family used in certain ways, even in cases where you can prove it's still a valid functor.